# Unresponsive UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R language/Shiny. I have created a shiny app that goes back and forth between pages. The problem is that once I click the "Back" button, it takes me back to the previous, but the links or buttons on that page don't work. I am facing this problem for all the pages I have created. The buttons or links don't work a second time. I am sharing the code below for a better understanding of the problem. Assume all the required libraries are installed and loaded

**ui.R

```
devtools::install_github("nstrayer/shinyswipr")
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(aos)
library(shinyswipr)
library(shinyanimate)
library(stringr)
library(shinyvalidate)
library(shinycssloaders)

# source("navbar.R")
source("registerPortal.R")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    tags$style(
        
        type = "text/css",
        
        "#header {position: relative; margin-top: -2%; height: 19vh; width: 92%,}",
        "#title {font-family: calibri; font-size: 35px; margin-top: -6%; position: relative; left: 8%; color: #223300;}",
        "#user .bttn-success{position: relative; margin-left: 93.3%; margin-top: 2%; font-family: calibri; color: #fff; opacity: 0.35; font-size: 16px;}",
        "#capitals {display: inline}",
        "#founder {margin-left:0%; margin-top:-2%;}",
        "#sign {margin-top:1%;}",
        ".action_button_capitals {position: relative; margin-left: 80px}",
        ".btnborder {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 1.7px solid #d6f39b;}",
        "a {color: #666;}", 
        "a:hover {color: #000;}", 
        "#navbar {font-size: 15px}",
        ".circle {background: #fff; border: 1.7px solid #d6f39b; border-radius: 50%; width: 222.7px; height: 220px; display: inline-block; margin: 70px;}",
        ".vpb1 .bttn-primary{background-color: #d6f39b; font-size: 17px; font-family: calibri; color: #232b2b; opacity: 0.8; left: 65px;}",
        ".vpb2 .bttn-primary{background-color: #d6f39b; font-size: 17px; font-family: calibri; color: #232b2b; opacity: 0.8; left: 69px;}",
        ".vpb3 .bttn-primary{background-color: #d6f39b; font-size: 17px; font-family: calibri; color: #232b2b; opacity: 0.8; left: 72px;}",
        ".vpb4 .bttn-primary{background-color: #d6f39b; font-size: 17px; font-family: calibri; color: #232b2b; opacity: 0.8; left: 75px;}",
        "#circletext1 {position: relative; left: 32px; font-size: 27px;}",  
        "#circletext2 {position: relative; left: 12px; font-size: 27px;}",
        "#circletext3 {position: relative; left: 25px; font-size: 27px;}",
        "#circletext4 {position: relative; left: 27px; font-size: 27px;}",
        "#aimg {position: relative; left: 75px; margin-top: 22%}",
        "#vimg {position: relative; left: 89px; margin-top: 22%}",
        "#mimg {position: relative; left: 89px; margin-top: 22%}",
        "#wimg {position: relative; left: 89px; margin-top: 22%}",
        "#alead {position: relative; left: -50px; margin-top: 5%}",
        "#vlead {position: relative; left: -50px; margin-top: 5%}",
        "#mlead {position: relative; left: -50px; margin-top: 5%}",
        "#wlead {position: relative; left: -50px; margin-top: 5%}",
        "#vdone {position: relative;  width: 27%; margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 177.1px;}",
        "#vdtwo {position: relative; margin-top: -38%; margin-left: 888.1px; width: 27%;}",
        "#vdthree {position: relative; margin-top: 5%; right: 120px; width: 30%; height: 50% color: green; text-align: center; color: white}",
        "#vdfour {position: relative; margin-top: -4.5%; left: 300px; width: 75%; height: 85vh; color: green; background-color: #E0F8AE; border: 7px solid  #E0F8AE;}",
        "#vdfive {position: relative; margin-top: -44.3%; left: 81.45%; width: 200px; height: 5vh; color: green; text-align: center; color: white;}",
        "#btn1 {background-color: #f1ffd4; margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 65px; border: none; color: #223300; text-size: 20px;}",
        "#btn2 {background-color: #f1ffd4; margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 87px; border: none; color: #223300; text-size: 20px;}",
        "#outer {position:relatice; margin-top:3%;}",
        ".button {background-color: #E0F8AE; border-color: #E0F8AE; color: #223300; width: 200px;}",
        "#about {position: relative; right: -40px; border-style: solid; border-color: #E0F8AE; color: #223300; width: 95%; padding: 30px; font-size: 16px;}",
        "#icons {margin-left: 61px; padding: 10px; padding-left: -2em; padding-right: -1em; margin-top:-1%;}",
        ".mydiv {width:100%; height:170px; background-color: #E0F8AE; opacity:0.9}",
        ".mytext {display: inline;  font-size: 13px;}",
        ".footertext {text-indent: 40%;}","#outer {position:relatice; margin-top:3%;}",
        "#user .bttn-primary{position: relative; margin-left: 94%; margin-top:1%; background-color: #d6f39b;  font-family: calibri; color: #232b2b; opacity: 0.8; font-size: 17px;}",
        
        
    ),  
    
    
    #Logo inserted
    div(id="header",
        
        
        
        #Main Title
        h1(id="title", "JAMIAAT: Data Analytics & Visualization for HEI's of Pakistan"),
    ),
    
    br(),
    br(),
    
    
    tags$div(id = "reg",
             shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
             register),
    
    uiOutput("display")
    
    
))

**registerPortal.R

register <-  fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(
    
    type = "text/CSS",
    
    " .has-error{color: #B31B1B;}"
  ),
  
  #User Registration
  div(id ="user", actionBttn("OPEN"," Register",
                             color = "success", style = "gradient", icon = icon("user"))),
  
  div(
    #Founder
    
    br(),
    
    
    div(id="founder",
    
    br(),
    
    
    h2(" There are two powers in the world; one is the sword and the other is the pen. There is a great competition and rivalry between the two. There is a third power stronger than both, that of the women." ,sep="<br/>")),
    
    
    
    
    br(),
    
  
  #Capitals Section
  
  br(),
  
  hr(),
  
  use_aos(disable = "mobile"), # add use_aos() in the UI
  aos(
    element =      div( id = "capitals",
                        
                        withAnim(),
                        actionButton(
                          inputId = "showISL", "ISL",
                          class = "action_button_capitals"
                        ),
                        
                        actionButton(
                          inputId = "showKARACHI", "Karachi",
                          class = "action_button_capitals"
                        ),
                        
                        actionButton(
                          inputId = "showLAHORE", "Lahore",
                          class = "action_button_capitals"
                        ),
                        
                        actionButton(
                          inputId = "showPESHAWAR", "Peshawar",
                          class = "action_button_capitals"
                        ),
                        
                        actionButton(
                          inputId = "showQUETTA", "Quetta",
                          class = "action_button_capitals"
                        )
    ),
    animation = "fade-up", 
    duration = "3000"),
  
  
  hr(),
  
  
  ) 
  
)
```

**islamabad.R

```
islamabad <- fluidPage(
  
  
  
  
  tags$style(
    
    type = "text/css",
    
    "#header {position: relative; margin-top: 1%; height: 19vh; width: 92%,}",
    "#title {font-family: calibri; font-size: 35px; margin-top: -6%; position: relative; left: 8%; color: #223300;}",
    "#heading {margin-top: 3%; position: relative; background-color: #E0F8AE; opacity: 0.9; font-family: calibri; height:30%; border: 1px solid #d6f39b; text-align:center;}",
    "#pointer {cursor: pointer;}",
    ".box {background: #fff; border: 1.7px solid #d6f39b; width:270px; height: 230px; display: inline-block; margin: 70px; margin-left:8.7%; cursor: pointer}",
    ".btnborder {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 1.7px solid #d6f39b;}",
    
  ), 
  
  
  #Heading
  div(id="heading", h4("Islamabad Universities"), ),
  
  
  actionButton(
    inputId = "back", "Back",
    class = "action_button_back"
  ),
  
  
  
  
  #Islamabad Universities
  
  
  withAnim(),
  
  tags$div(id = 'nust', class = "box", div(br(), align = "center"), 
           br(),
           h5("National University of Sciences and Technology", align = "center"),
           actionButton("showNUST", "View Info", class="btnborder")),
  
  tags$div(id = 'fast', class = "box", div(br(), align = "center"), 
           br(),
           h5("National University of Computer and Emerging Sciences", align = "center"),
           actionButton("showFAST", "View Info", class="btnborder")),
  
  tags$div(id = 'qau', class = "box", div(br(),  align = "center"), 
           br(),
           h5("Quaid-i-Azam University", align = "center"),
           actionButton("showQAU", "View Info", class="btnborder")),
  
  
)
```

**server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(RMySQL)

useShinyjs()  
source("islamabad.R")

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
    #User-Registration Button
    observeEvent(input$OPEN, {
        showModal(modalDialog( id = "form",
                               h3(strong("User Sign-Up Portal"), align = "center"),
                               
                               
                               br(),
                               
                               textInput("Username", "Enter Username:", value = "", placeholder = "Username"),
                               textInput("Email", "Enter Email:", value = "", placeholder = "Email"),
                               passwordInput("Password", "Enter Password:", value = "", placeholder = "Password"),
                               passwordInput("rePassword", "Retype Password:", value = "", placeholder = "Retype Password"),
                               
                               easyClose = TRUE,
                               footer=tagList(
                                   p("Already have an account ? Click to Sign In"),actionButton('signin', 'Sign-In'),
                                   
                                   div(style = "margin-right: 300px", actionButton('submit', 'Submit'), actionButton("refresh", "Refresh"),
                                       modalButton('cancel'))
                               )
        )
        )
        uiOutput("successReg")
    }
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$showNUST, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
            h4("National University of Sciences & Technology", align = "center"),
            hr(),
            h5("Motto   :"),
            h6("Defining Futures"),
            h5("Type :"),
            h6("Public"),
            h5("Established :"),
            h6("1991; 29 years ago"),
            h5("Academic Staff :"),
            h6("817"),
            h5("Students :"),
            h6("6,259"),
            h5("Undergraduates :"),
            h6("938"),
            h5("Postgraduates :"),
            h6("3,859"),
            h5("Website:"),
            a("http://nust.edu.pk/", href = "http://nust.edu.pk/"),
            h5("Location :"),
            h6("Islamabad, Pakistan"),
            h5("Affiliations :"),
            tags$ul(
                tags$li(h6("Higher Education Commission of Pakistan")),
                tags$li(h6("Pakistan Engineering Council")),
                tags$li(h6("Washington Accord"))
            ),
            hr(),
            p("Click your cursor anywhere outside Pop-Up-Modal screen to close it", style="color: #8A9A5B; font-size: 12.7px"),
            easyClose = TRUE,
            footer = NULL
        ))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$showFAST, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
            h4("National University of Computer and Emerging Sciences", align = "center"),
            hr(),
            h5("Former Names    :"),
            h6("FAST Institute of Computer Science"),
            h5("Motto :"),
            h6("Ø§ÙØ°Û Ø¹ÙÙ Ø¨Ø§ÙÙÙÙÛ Ø¹ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ§ÙØ³Ø§Ù ÙØ§ ÙÙ ÙØ¹ÙÙÛ"),
            h5("Motto in English    :"),
            h6("Who has taught by the pen, has taught man that which he knew not. ~ Al-Quran (A verse from Holy Book of Muslims)."),
            h5("Type :"),
            h6("Non-Profite Private"),
            h5("Established :"),
            h6("2000"),
            h5("Parent Institutuion :"),
            h6("Foundation for Advancement of Science and Technology (Established in 1980)"),
            h5("Students :"),
            h6("11,000"),
            h5("Campus :"),
            h6("Faisalabad, Karachi, Lahore, Peshawar, Islamabad"),
            h5("Website:"),
            a("http://nu.edu.pk/", href = "http://nu.edu.pk/"),
            h5("Location :"),
            h6("Islamabad, Pakistan"),
            h5("Affiliations :"),
            tags$ul(
                tags$li(h6("Higher Education Commission of Pakistan")),
                tags$li(h6("Pakistan Engineering Council"))
            ),
            hr(),
            p("Click your cursor anywhere outside Pop-Up-Modal screen to close it", style="color: #8A9A5B; font-size: 12.7px"),
            easyClose = TRUE,
            footer = NULL
        ))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$showQAU, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
            h4("Quaid-i-Azam University", align = "center"),
            hr(),
            h5("Former Names    :"),
            h6("University of Islamabad"),
            h5("Motto :"),
            h6("ÙÙÙÙÙ ÙÙØ¤ÙØªÙ Ø§ÙÙØ­ÙÙÙÙÙØ©Ù ÙÙÙÙØ¯Ù Ø£ÙÙØªÙÙÙ Ø®ÙÙÙØ±ÙØ§ ÙÙØ«ÙÙØ±ÙØ§"),
            h5("Motto in English    :"),
            h6("And he to whom wisdom is granted receiveth indeed a benefit overflowing"),
            h5("Type :"),
            h6("Public"),
            h5("Established :"),
            h6("July 22, 1967; 53 years ago"),
            h5("Students :"),
            h6("13,000"),
            h5("Campus :"),
            h6("Urban"),
            h5("Website:"),
            a("http://qau.edu.pk/", href = "http://qau.edu.pk/"),
            h5("Location :"),
            h6("Islamabad, Pakistan"),
            h5("Affiliations :"),
            tags$ul(
                tags$li(h6("Higher Education Commission of Pakistan"))
            ),
            hr(),
            p("Click your cursor anywhere outside Pop-Up-Modal screen to close it", style="color: #8A9A5B; font-size: 12.7px"),
            easyClose = TRUE,
            footer = NULL
        ))
    })
    
    
    #Hover Animation Observe Event for Islamabad Universities
    observe(addHoverAnim(session, 'nust', 'pulse'))
    observe(addHoverAnim(session, 'fast', 'pulse'))
    observe(addHoverAnim(session, 'qau', 'pulse'))
    
    
   
    
    
    
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$showISL, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("reg")
            islamabad
        })
        
    })
    observeEvent(input$showKARACHI, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("reg")
            islamabad
        })
        
    })
    observeEvent(input$showLAHORE, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("reg")
            islamabad
        })
        
    })
    observeEvent(input$showPESHAWAR, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("reg")
            islamabad
        })
        
    })
    observeEvent(input$showQUETTA, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("reg")
            islamabad
        })
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$back, {
        
        output$display <- renderUI({
            shinyjs::hide("display")
            shinyjs::show("reg")
        })
        
    })
    
    
    
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Unfortunately, your code is not a minimal reproducible example because it references file(s) [for example `JTLogo.png`] that we cannot access.  It also clearly isn't *minimal*.  You're much more likely to get useful answers to your question if you provide code that others can run and which *focuses* on your problem.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I edited my code. Please have a look!

Comment: Hopefully @SmokeyShakers' answer has put you on the right track.  Their suggestion certainly is credible.  Personally, I am not prepared to install seven packages and work my way through over 400 lines of code to see what the problem *might* be.

Answer (score 0):

This section at the bottom of you server.R file should not be a `renderUI`

```
observeEvent(input$back, {
    
    output$display <- renderUI({
        shinyjs::hide("display")
        shinyjs::show("reg")
    })
    
})
```

You just want to issue those commands when the back button is pressed, like this:

```
observeEvent(input$back, {
        shinyjs::hide("display")
        shinyjs::show("reg")  
})
```